# Typescript module, require external node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to use a simple node_module inside a simple typescript file, but it seems that the compiler doesn't want to get it.

Here's my simple ts file :

```
import glob = require('glob');
console.log(glob);
```

And I've got this error :

```
[13:51:11] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.5.0
[13:51:12] [tsc] > F:/SkeletonProject/boot/ts/Boot.ts(4,23): error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'glob'.
[13:51:12] Failed to compile TypeScript: Error: tsc command has exited with code:2

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Failed to compile: tsc command has exited with code:2

npm ERR! skeleton-typescript-name@0.0.1 start: `node compile && node ./boot/js/Boot.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the skeleton-typescript-name@0.0.1 start script.
```

However, when I use a simple declaration in this same script, it works :

```
var x = 0;
console.log(x); // prints  0 after typescript compilation
```

What am I doing wrong in this case ?

EDIT:

Here's my gulp file :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');


gulp.task('compileApp', ['compileBoot'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['app/src/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/'))
});

gulp.task('compileBoot', function () {
    return gulp.src(['boot/ts/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typescript({
            module:'commonjs'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('boot/js/'))
});

gulp.start('compileApp');
```

Thanks for advance

Thanks for advance

Comment: Pretty sure you should simply write `import glob` or `import 'glob'`

Comment: import glob; throw me an error in IDE, and how should I refer to my library when using import 'glob' ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: It should be var glob = require('glob'); Y do you use import also?

Comment: Isn't this the standard typescript metod with import ?

Comment: Do you have correct `--module` option specified for the typescript compiler? For node it should be `--module commonjs`

Comment: i've editted my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the correct syntax:

```
import glob = require('glob');
```

But the error: `Cannot find external module 'glob'` is pointing out that you are using a special case.

By default, the compiler is looking for `glob.ts`, but in your case you are using a node module, not a module that you have written. For this reason, the `glob` module will need special treatment...

If `glob` is a plain JavaScript module, you can add a file named `glob.d.ts` with type information that described the module.

*glob.d.ts*

```
declare module "glob" {
    export class Example {
        doIt(): string;
    }
}
```

*app.ts*

```
import glob = require('glob');

var x = new glob.Example();
```

Some Node modules already include the `.d.ts` in the package, in other cases you can grab it from [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

Comment: It's really hard to manage and declare every modules with TypeScript so :-o . Is the Definitely Typed source really up to date and sure ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Definitely Typed is community maintained and is currently receiving updates daily: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/commits/master

Answer (score -3):

Here is the error with your code

```
    import glob = require('glob');
```

Because in node.js import is not a reserved keyword. If you require any module in your application, you simply require it using the statement

```
    var glob = require('glob');
```

Once done you can then use

```
    console.log(glob);
```

To print the value of glob.Replacing import will hopefully do the job for you.

Comment: I m in a typescript file

Comment: please take the reference of this stackoverflow question in that case                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958479/typescript-module-import-in-nodejs