# How to import typescript file in javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to import a typescript file (`src/index.ts`) in a javascript file(`tests/steps/utils.js`)

But when I use `const index_1 = require("../../src/index");` in my javascript file, it gives an error: `Cannot find module '../../src/index'`

But the file is right there. Is there any other way to import a typescript file into a javascript file?

Comment: try to import from dist folder, where the ts compiler output path.

Comment: yes, i can do that but I was hoping if there is any other way to import the typescript file directly

Comment: @SalmanArefin Node.js cannot parse TypeScript files.

Comment: Typescript and Javascript are not the same language. `require()` is looking for .js file, not .ts. You should transpile typescript code to javascript if you really need to do this import.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958479/typescript-module-import-in-nodejs

Answer (score 6):

You can't. You need to compile the typescript files into js first. However, you can import the built typescript file i.e. js file from its   build directory.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated May 2023:**
Just found this library: [ts-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-import), it seems can import TS into JS project already.

---

You can't import a ts into js file.

If you really need the module in .ts file, try to import from dist folder, where the ts compiler output path, or refactor into javascript.

Comment: Not sure about the time you posted this, but now you can import ts into js and works just fine! please correct me if missing sth

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). These tools allow `js` and `ts` to be used together in both development and build.

`.babelrc` file (pay attention to `@babel/preset-typescript`):

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

and add something like this to `webpack.config.js` (pay attention to `ts` in `rules/babel-loader`):

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|ts|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Full disclaimer: I'm the author of the proposed solution below*

You can use [`import-single-ts`](https://github.com/antitoxic/import-single-ts) which is a drop-in replacement for the `JS`-native `import(..)` but it also works for `TypeScript` by compiling it on-the-fly.

So instead of doing `await import('./some.js')` you just do `await importSingleTs('./some.ts')`. No config or extra compilation step necessary.

It's super tiny & very fast since it uses `esbuild` and not `tsc` or `babel` which the other solutions offer.

---

Full example:

```
import { importSingleTs } from 'import-single-ts';
// or for cjs: const { importSingleTs } = require('import-single-ts');
// ...
await importSingleTs('./some.ts'); // place where you need it
```